# Is there any way to open an URL inside app instead of browser in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. URL_ LAUNCHER opens URL on a web browser
2. But I want to show URL inside my app INSTEAD OF any browser
3. How can I achieve this ?
4. Whenever user click on a button url should launch inside my app instead of any default web browser or any type of browser

Comment: Use [webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this Flutter plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('WebView example'),
          ),
          body: const WebView(
            initialUrl: 'SOME URL',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
        );
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer ...Is this   plugin going to display linear/horizontal progress bar  status in the app bar section?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs) library to launch urls inside of your app on Android (this is the default behavior for url_launcher on iOS

Comment: Thank you for this plugin... I was searching for this pugin to make my job easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin to achieve that.

Simple example:

```
WebView( 
  initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
)
```

To answer your second question:

> Is this plugin going to display linear/horizontal progress bar status in the app bar section?

The `WebView` is just like any other flutter widget so yes, you can show linear/horizontal progress bar in your `AppBar` they way you have planned it.